# How can I use the LayerPosition.at() method effectively in Mapbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

Mapbox iOS SDK has a [method](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.0.1/Enums/LayerPosition.html#/s:10MapboxMaps13LayerPositionO2atyACSicACmF) `.at()` defined simply as

```
/// Layer should be positioned at the specified index in the layers stack.
case at(Int)
```

This seems like an easy use case, but Mapbox seems to have all the layers, names, location, everything also using this same system and **it's not clear to me what number I should use to make a route line appear over all that boilerplate and still have granular control.**

Now the other methods like `.below()` and `.above()` take in a string of the layer ID, which means I can pass around the names of my overlays and add things above and below them. But `.at()` simply takes an `Int`, which makes it difficult to easily compare to other layers and make use of it in a clean way.

I'm having trouble finding examples using it effectively, so can someone direct me to what a good use of this API is?

Answer (score 0):

`allLayersIdentifiers` shows the current order of all layers: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.16.1/Classes/Style.html#/s:10MapboxMaps5StyleC19allLayerIdentifiersSayAA0E4InfoVGvp

`moveLayer()` moves already added layers:
https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.16.1/Classes/Style.html#/s:10MapboxMaps5StyleC9moveLayer6withId2toySS_AA0E8PositionOtKF

These helped me see how everything is organized and makes for easy usage of functions like `.at()`, `.below()`, and `.above()`